# How to sync remote special files with scp?

Tags: linux, synchronization, scp

Want sync all remote files like `20170208*` to local, but this not work:

```
$ scp user@remote-server:/home/user/20170208* .
```

I also tried

```
$ scp user@remote-server:/home/user/\{20170208*\} .
```

That doesn't work, too. Because of zsh doesn't know: `scp user@remote-server:/home/user/{20170208*} .`

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please quote it 
**scp 'user@remote-server:/home/user/20170208*' .**

Or escape your wildcard

**scp user@remote-server:/home/user/20170208\* .**